# Invite over something

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, phrase-usage, phrase-request

I'm planning to ask someone out for a chat over a coffee or something light. Is following lines correct and common english(US)?

1. Can I invite you for a chat over coffee/tea?
2. Can I invite you for a chat over something light?(I mean a small casual drink or small bite)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are fine for casual communication.  The first is more clear than the second - I have never had someone invite me over for "something light."

However, you might consider posing a direct question.  For example, "Would you like to join for a bite?"

Comment: I agree: “Can I invite you” is very formal—which is fine if the purpose of the chat is business. Otherwise, “Would you like to get coffee sometime?” would be more natural.